# How can you configure nowjs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, nowjs-sockets

With nowjs how do I configure the lower level socket.io's logging level and it's per connection (global) authentication level?

For example if I were just using socket.io I would use the following code:

```
socketServer.configure(function (){  
  socketServer.set('authorization', function (handshakeData, callback) { 
    callback(null, true); // error first callback style 
  });  
  socketServer.set('log level', 1);
});
```

Thanks!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can pass in socket.io options in the nowjs.initialize() call under the `socketio` key.

Example:

```
 nowjs.initialize(httpServer, {socketio: {'log level': 1, 'authorization': myfunc}});
```